# How to know where plugged device was mounted?

Tags: mount, filesystem, devices, mountpoint

For example I have 3G modem. When I plug it in USB port it becomes `/dev/ttyACM0`.

- How can I see if device is really connected at all, what proper commands to see listings of connected devices (not only on USB port)?
- How to determine which device mounted where, so if I see my modem in listing, how can I find where its mounted in filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

I use `mount` whitout argument to see all mounted device.

For example, list of mounted disk, I use : `mount | grep /dev/sd`

Answer (score 0):

A couple commands that will be useful for this.

`lsusb`: lists connected usb devices

`lspci`: list information about PCI buses and connected devices

`df`: used to show free disk space, but it is also useful to see the mount points of different devices.

Also check out the man pages for each of these commands.